# Embedded Linux - skip file system check if .mount unit is skipped

Tags: linux, systemd, fsck

I'm working on a custom stm32-based board running a Linux distribution built with buildroot. The system can either boots from an SD card or a eMMC flash.

SystemD is installed. The rootfs is mounted in read-only mode so applications can save data to a read-write partition on the eMMC.

This data partition is mounted only when booting from the eMMC flash. To achieve this I created a systemd file named `data.mount` so I could add a condition to mount the partition when I want with `ConditionKernelCommandLine`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount persistent data partition in operating mode
Before=local-fs.target
DefaultDependencies=no
ConditionKernelCommandLine=device=emmc

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-label/data
Where=/data
Type=ext4
Options=defaults,noatime
```

If the board boots from the SD card then the data partition is not mounted but is still checked by systemd-fsck. An implicit service `systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-data.service` is executed.

The issue is when the partition is not present in the eMMC, systemd-fsck is waiting for the partition to be present. It waits for 90s.

Because of the conditions I was expecting that even the fsck dependencies were not executed.

With the kernel command I can disable systemd-fsck but I would like to disable it only for the data partition when the partition is not present.

Any idea ?